# Asymptotic Estimate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Consider the following Sturm–Liouville problem $$u''+\lambda u=0, \ 0<x<1$$ $$u(0)-u'(0)=0, \ u(1)+u'(1)=0.$$
>   Obtain an asymptotic estimate for large eigenvalues.

I solved the problem and got the transcendental equation $\tan\sqrt{\lambda}=\frac{2\sqrt{\lambda}}{\lambda-1}.$

But how do I obtain an asymptotic estimate? I know I can use Herman Weyl formula $\int^b_a\sqrt{\frac{r(x)}{p(x)}}dx,$ but I don't know how to apply it here.

Comment: Actually you should have obtained $$\tan(\sqrt{\lambda}) = \dfrac{2\sqrt{\lambda}}{\lambda - 1}$$
Or should that $\lambda$ in the equation have been $\lambda^2$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael You're right. I am going to edit.

Comment: Are you looking for the large $\lambda$ solutions to that equation?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I believe so because I must take the limit as $n\to \infty$

Comment: I would start by noticing that as $\lambda \to \infty$ you have $$\tan \sqrt{\lambda} = \frac{2\sqrt{\lambda}}{\lambda - 1} \sim \frac{2}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \to 0,$$ so $\lambda_n = n^2 \pi^2 + o(1)$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ just an approximation, right? You didn't derive it from a formula. Also, how did you get $\lambda=n^2\pi^2$?

Comment: Right, $2\sqrt{\lambda}/(\lambda - 1) \approx 2\sqrt{\lambda}/\lambda = 2/\sqrt{\lambda}$ for large $\lambda$.  And if $\tan x \approx 0$ then $x \approx n\pi$ for some integer $n$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thank you very much!

Comment: @AntonioVargas Actually not $o(1)$, rather $O(1)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, ah, the $(\cdots)^2$ changes it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda = x^2$ so $\tan(x) = 2x/(x^2-1)$.  It's easy to see that there is exactly one solution $x_n$ for $x$ in each interval $((n-1/2)\pi, (n+1/2)\pi)$, and (as has been remarked) $\tan x_n \to 0$ so $x_n - n \pi \to 0$.
For a more detailed approximation, note that if $x_n = n \pi + a_1/n + a_2/n^2 + O(1/n^3)$ we have  $$
\eqalign{\tan x_n &= \dfrac{\tan(a_1/n) + \tan(a_2/n^2) + O(1/n^3)}{1 - \tan(a_1/n) \tan(a_2/n^2) + O(1/n^3)} = \dfrac{a_1}{n} + \dfrac{a_2}{n^2} + O(1/n^3)\cr
\dfrac{2 x_n}{x_n^2 - 1} &= \dfrac{2}{\pi n} + O(1/n^3)\cr}$$
so that $a_1 = 2/\pi$ and $a_2 = 0$.  Thus 
$$ x_n = n \pi + \dfrac{2}{n\pi} + O(1/n^3)$$
and so 
$$ \lambda_n = n^2 \pi^2 + 4 + O(1/n^2)$$